# Как положить webpack config file в node_modules?

Tags: webpack, node-modules, webpack4, webpack2

подскажите пожалуйста кто в курсе, как положить webpack config (например create react app webpack.configs) в node_modules? чтобы потом он по дефолту применялся как основа для разных проектов?

перерыл Google, к сожалению не особо помогло в решении поставленной задачи.

Answer (score 0):

Вы решаете проблему не предназначенным для этого способом и у вас это в принципе не выйдет осуществить. Как вариант вы можете сконфигурировать шаблон и запушить его себе на github, чтобы потом использовать на разных проектах.